# How to redirect using ActionLink to specific View tab region in ASP .NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, redirect, tabs, actionlink

I need to make an ActionLink that redirects to the previous page, but the previous page is divided in 5 tabs. So for the URL say

`host/Admin/AdminMain`

which has the tabs, when I hover over tabs the link appears to be

```
host/Admin/AdminMain#tabs-1
host/Admin/AdminMain#tabs-2
```

and so on.

In tabs-2 I have a link to another View, like host/Admin/SomeController, and there I need to create the ActionLink in the View that redirects me back to tabs-2, instead of tabs-1 as it does. The ActionLink right now looks like this:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Back to Main", "Index", "AdminMain")
```

How can I specify to redirect me to #tabs-2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `#tabs-2` portion is called the "fragment" of the URL. It's not actually part of the URI for the resource, and is only used client-side to "jump" the user to portion of the document with that id.

However, something like tabs require JavaScript to function, and the browser cannot automatically switch to a tab based on the fragment, because it doesn't know *how* to do that. You'd need to write some JavaScript read the fragment and then attempt to activate the appropriate tab, using whatever library you're using for that.

```
(function () {
    var fragment = location.hash;
    if (fragment !== '') {
        // activate tab with that id
    }
})();
```

Comment: Thanks. I don't know a lot about JS and didn't know I have to use it in order to solve this. I did some digging and solved the problem. Thank you again!